react dnd-kit on Drag end set input focus, but cannot type
Here is a simple reproduce of my issue. I'm using Nextjs, react, @dnd-kit/core, typescript.
Normally if I do testRef?.current?.focus(), the input field will have the cursor and if I directly type on keyboard, the value would change. But in this case I cannot type, but the outline of the input field and the log indicate that the focus is triggered. ONLY THAT I CANNOT Type.
"use client";

import {
  DragEndEvent,
  useDndMonitor,
  useDraggable,
  useDroppable,
} from "@dnd-kit/core";
import React, { useRef } from "react";

function page() {
  const testRef = useRef(null);

  useDndMonitor({
    onDragEnd: (event: DragEndEvent) => {
      if (testRef.current) {
        console.log("focus");
        (testRef?.current as HTMLInputElement).focus();
      }
    },
  });

  const draggable = useDraggable({
    id: "drag",
  });

  const droppable = useDroppable({
    id: "drop",
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        ref={draggable.setNodeRef}
        {...draggable.listeners}
        {...draggable.attributes}
        className="h-10 w-10 border border-yellow-200"
      >
        drag
      </div>
      <div
        ref={droppable.setNodeRef}
        className="h-10 w-10 border border-green-200"
      >
        drop
      </div>

      <form onSubmit={() => console.log("submit")}>
        <input ref={testRef} defaultValue={"default "} />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default page;

I think it is the useDndMonitor makes it weird behind the scene because if it is a button on click listener, it would set the focus just fine.
But the very first of all, I want to know that why the text field is focused but not really (cannot type). Is the focus lost else where after the drag end?
Expect from answers:

How to make it work (after drop, it set the focus correctly, so that user can type directly)
The root cause of this issue.


It seems  setTimeout(() => testRef.current.focus(), 50)  works. But don't know why, maybe wait for the component render finish. You should post an issue on GitHub or discussion. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-zqr3j9?file=src%2FApp.tsx
